# Code::Blocks export as pdf in landscape page layout

Tags: codeblocks

Is there a way to export to pdf in landscape page layout in Code::Blocks?
I can set layout when I print, but there is no such option in "Export" menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with Code::blocks. We can use another software **Primopdf** PDF Converter download free and install it form [here](http://www.primopdf.com/). Now from Code::blocks go to print menu->select PrimoPDF as printer form printer list. From preference option you can set landscape page layout.After this press the print button and this means you are sending the document to the primoPDF software to convert it into pdf.
[image: Exporting to primoPDF]

Now primoPDF software will open.Press create PDF option and you get option to save pdf document in your hard drive.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its now availabe under files->export->as pdf